# How to lock the content again, if the user turn off the Automatic Renewal Subscription IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

How to lock the content again if the user turns off the automatic renewal subscription or subscription expired? Note: I am not asking about the cancellation of the subscription.

If I compare `expiration_date` the with `[NSDate date]` current date, it's working fine. But problem is if user changes the current date from the iPhone settings before reaching the expiration date. The content will never lock again.
What is the correct way to handle this?

```
{
    "original_purchase_date_ms":"1440803196000",
    "original_purchase_date_pst":"2015-08-28 16:06:36 America/Los_Angeles",
    "transaction_id":"1000000169694402",
    "quantity":"1",
    "original_purchase_date":"2015-08-28 23:06:36 Etc/GMT",
    "original_transaction_id":"1000000169694402",
    "purchase_date":"2015-08-28 23:08:34 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date_pst":"2015-08-28 16:08:34 America/Los_Angeles",
    "product_id":"com.domain.ck",
    "purchase_date_ms":"1440803315000",
    "expires_date":"2015-08-28 23:13:34 Etc/GMT",
    "expires_date_ms":"1440803614000",
    "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000030675618",
    "is_trial_period":"false",
    "expires_date_pst":"2015-08-28 16:13:34 America/Los_Angeles"
},
```